# How do I toggle the content of the other bootstrap buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using **bootstrap** and **scss** to create a wordpress page but i'm having some issues trying to create a collapsable content. I have four buttons and I want that only the content of one of them is displayed while the others are collapsed. If I click the second button for example the buttons 1, 3 & 4 should display nothing.

Also I have a active class to show in a clear way which one is pressed that it's not working properly. Any help would be really nice, thanks!

```js
    var mainStarter = {
      initialize: function() {
        this.buttonActive();
        this.toggleButton();
      },

      buttonActive: function() {
        $(".btn.btn-bg-md").on("click", function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
      },

      toggleButton: function() {
        $('.column button').click(function() {
          $(".collapse:visible").add($(this).next()).slideToggle();

        });
      },


      $(function() {
        mainStarter.initialize();
      });
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <div class="column">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-bg-md" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#btn1" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
            <h6>Day 1</h6>
          </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <div class="column">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-bg-md" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#btn2" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
            <h6>Day 2</h6>
          </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Item 3 -->
  <div class="column">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-bg-md" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#btn3" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
            <h6>Day 3</h6>
          </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Item 4 -->
  <div class="column">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-bg-md" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#btn4" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
            <h6>Day 4</h6>
          </button>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse" id="btn1">
      <h1>Something 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse" id="btn2">
      <h1>Something 2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse" id="btn3">
      <h1>Something 3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse" id="btn4">
      <h1>Something 4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you really want (your message is not that clear). What I understood, is that you want 2 buttons. When you click the first one, it shows the 1st message and hide the second. When you click the second, it shows the second message and hides the first one. If i understood correctly, you could use jquery, using the correct ids on the divs

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    if ($("#collapsebutton2").is(":visible")) {
    $("#collapsebutton2").toggle( "slow", function() {

    });
  }
  $("#collapsebutton1").toggle( "slow", function() {

  });

});

$("#button2").click(function() {
  $("#collapsebutton2").toggle( "slow", function() {

  });

  if ($("#collapsebutton2").is(":visible")) {
    $("#collapsebutton1").toggle( "slow", function() {

  });
  }
});
```